# All pagers stopped working

Tags: 7, paging

I have a Drupal 7 site built in 2014 with numerous pagers built in.  Most of the pagers are in custom modules and are rendered using the following code.

```php
$pager = theme('pager', array('quantity' => 10));
```

A few months ago they all stopped working. The pager shows up at the bottom of the screen, but the URLs do not have the `?page=x` part in the query.

Does anyone have any idea about this?

Comment: The question is - is the parameter just filtered out or the pager is not set? I am sure you did it already, thus it would be good to share what happens if (1) You add to the URL the parameter ?page=2 manually and hit enter; (2) you click on rendered pager's value '2'...?

Comment: If I enter the value manually in the URL it works as intended.  The pager returned from the theme function has no query attached.
So the pager is there, and the appropriate number of pages show in the pager, but every link from the pager (including next and last, point to the same place.